# Rails 3 routing error, User class with Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I'm trying to create a profile page for my users, but I get stuck as soon as the user logs in, due to routing error. Even if I try to load the first page, I get the same problem again. When I do a rake routes, I get these user paths:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter/}
  user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook|twitter)
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy

users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
```

This is what my Users::OmniauthCallbacksController looks like:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure about this, but I thought I should create a UsersController in which I could implement methods outside of the device. This is what it looks like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @users = User.all

        respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ingredients }
    end
    end

    def profile
        @user = current_user

        respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @ingredients }
    end
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @ingredients }
    end
    end

end
```

In my routes.rb I have the following users related lines:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
resources :users
```

Now, If I load the first page while the user is logged in, I get the error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Hmm... well I have not cleared the server chache, but yes, I have restarted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example `routes.rb` file when using Devise along with a custom Users Controller. I was having trouble with some paths colliding, where I wanted requests to go to my Users controller, but they were going to Devise instead.

I had some specific issues with the registration URLs. You might either have to do something similar for the URLs you have trouble with or you might be able to get by with just the last line specifying your custom Users controller.

```
Railsappname::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"
 
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations]
 
  devise_scope :user do
    # make some pretty URLs
    get "login" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
    # rewrite the registrations URLs so they don't collide with my custom Users Controller
    get "signup" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
    put "update-registration" => "devise/registrations#update", :as => :update_user_registration
    delete "delete-registration" => "devise/registrations#destroy", :as => :delete_user_registration
    get "edit-registration" => "devise/registrations#edit", :as => :edit_user_registration
    get "cancel-registration" => "devise/registrations#cancel", :as => :cancel_user_registration
    post "create-registration" => "devise/registrations#create", :as => :user_registration
  end
 
  resources :users, :controller => "users"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the "devise users" and the "users" are attempting to take hold of the "/users" routes. The easiest way to solve this is to tell devise to use a prefix:

```
devise_for :users, 
  :path_prefix => 'auth', 
  :controllers => {
    :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" 
  }
resources :users
```

Now the devise authentication will post to "auth_users", and your CRUD will still do to "/users"